# How to set country (region) for WiFi globally in Linux Mint 20?

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, iwlwifi

Router: OpenWrt with `CZ` region successfully set for all WiFi adapters.

System: Linux Mint 20.1 Cinnamon, [official link](https://linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=284)

WiFi driver: `iwlwifi`:

```
readlink /sys/class/net/wlp60s0/device/driver
../../../../bus/pci/drivers/iwlwifi
```

### Problem:

```
iw reg get
```

shows `BZ` region, I remember to have set this region temporarily in my router, but not in computer(s).

### What I tried:

```
sudo iw reg set CZ
```

That on one computer worked until reboot, on a second computer did not work at all.

---

### Question

How to set country (region) for WiFi globally in Linux Mint 20.1 (Ubuntu 20.04 based) for the setting to apply across reboots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to find this file:

```
/etc/default/crda
```

which contains the following info:

> Set `REGDOMAIN` to a ISO/IEC 3166-1 alpha2 country code so that iw(8) may set the initial regulatory domain setting for IEEE 802.11 devices which operate on this system. Governments assert the right to regulate usage of radio spectrum within their respective territories so make sure you select a ISO/IEC 3166-1 alpha2 country code suitable for your location or you may infringe on local legislature. See `/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab` for a table of timezone descriptions containing ISO/IEC 3166-1 alpha2 country codes.

along with one setting only in my laptop, and blank (unset) on the second one:

```
REGDOMAIN=BZ
```

---

So the answer is to safely edit this file, e.g.:

```
sudoedit /etc/default/crda
```

editing the 2-letter country code.

---

To apply the new configuration:

```
sudo netplan apply
sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service
```